# How change state Openhab item using Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

How change state Openhab item using Jersey?

Source-code:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://demo.openhab.org:8080/rest");
WebTarget resourceWebTarget = webTarget.path("things");
Form form =new Form();
if (item.getState().equals("ON"))
   form.param("state", "OFF");
else
   form.param("state", "ON");
response = 
webTarget.path("items").path("Light_GF_Corridor_Ceiling").request()
.header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
.header("Accept", "application/json")        
.post(Entity.entity(form,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON),Response.class);
System.out.println("Status Info Response " + response.getStatusInfo());
```

Output:
    Status Info Response Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 0):

`Form` is not meant to be used with `application/json` (it's meant to be used with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). With JSON, you are either supposed to used POJOs, collections of POJOS, or Strings. If you want to send collections of POJOs, you need to wrap it in [`GenericEntity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html).